How to work with structure nested entries on live-preview?
Can I get some guidance/help on how to make work structure section type on the live preview please? Everything is fine when the section is a single or a channel.
I am working on a few projects, some using the structure where nested entry types (second level) are used to allow repositioning elements across the pages (first level)

Here where we can see what is going on on the preview editor(left), the draft (middle) and on the iframe (inspector highlighted in blue). Where the url and the tokens are being correctly generated.
When I make changes, the iframe refreshes, but not changes.
I am sending the token back in my request:
export const usePage = async (previewToken: string) => {
  console.log('Preview: ', previewToken)
  const route = useRoute()
  useGqlHeaders({ 'X-Craft-Token': previewToken || '' })

  const { data } = await useAsyncGql('page', {
    slug:
      route.path === '/'
        ? 'index'
        : route.params.slug
        ? route.params.slug[0]
        : route.params.deep
  })

  return data.value?.entry
}

Preview token on the console:

Straight from local url:

From a local preview folder:

Please let me know if you need anything else from me to help me out :)
Many thanks in advance.
